# Xcode 6.0.1 - error: CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=YES but EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY is unset or empty

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, cocoapods, provisioning-profile

I am working on an Objective-C project that was finished pre-Xcode 6, all written in Objective-C. I just got Xcode 6.0.1 for OS X Mavericks (10.9.4). When I go to build the app (no code changes) using Xcode 6.0.1, I get an issue under the Pods-app target with the following output:

```
*** error: CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=YES but EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY is unset or empty.: No such file or directory

swift-stdlib-tool --print
  Find and print the Swift libraries required by an app.

swift-stdlib-tool --copy
  Copy the Swift libraries into an app bundle, and optionally codesign them.

`--verbose` logs progress. 
`--verbose --verbose` prints debugging details.
`--help` prints this usage information. 

Environment variables from Xcode:
    SWIFT_LIBRARY_PATH
        Directory containing the Swift libraries.
SWIFT_EXEC
    Path to the Swift compiler. The Swift libraries are 
    found relative to it if SWIFT_LIBRARY_PATH is unset.
DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR
    Path to toolchain that contains the Swift libraries, 
    if SWIFT_LIBRARY_PATH and SWIFT_EXEC are unset.
PLATFORM_NAME
    macosx/iphoneos/iphonesimulator, for SWIFT_EXEC or DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR.

CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR
    Build destination containing the app bundle.
EXECUTABLE_PATH
    Path to app's executable, relative to build dir.
FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH
    Path to app's Frameworks folder, relative to build dir.
UNSIGNED_FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH
    Path to another Frameworks folder, relative to build dir.
    Files copied here are never codesigned.

EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY
    Code signing identity for /usr/bin/codesign.
CODE_SIGN_KEYCHAIN
    Optional keychain to search for the code signing identity.
CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=YES
    Perform code signing, if EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY is also set.
CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=YES
    Perform code signing, and fail if EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY
    is not set.

Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 1
```

Additional facts:

- Xcode 6.0.1 knows about my developer profile.
- Xcode 6.0.1 knows about the correct provisioning profile associated with said developer profile.
- I have set the **Provisioning Profile** setting in Xcode's Build Settings for the app target to said provisioning profile.
- I have set the **Release** Code Signing Identity to the identity associated with said provisioning profile.

Here is the question: why am I getting the error described in the Xcode output above?

**EDIT:**

After upgrading to OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks), I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating mavericks to version 10.9.5, I'm fairly sure this is an issue with Xcode 6.0.1 under 10.9.4